# The Quantum Statistical Average of the Energy-Momentum Tensor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, thermal-field-theory

Here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3521 and here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.6332 as well as elsewhere, the quantum statistical average of the energy-momentum tensor is taken to be

\begin{equation}   \left<\int_0^{\beta}d\tau\int{dx}^3\hat{T}^{\mu\nu}(\tau,x)\right>=\frac{\operatorname{Tr}\left[\int_0^{\beta}d\tau\int{dx}^3\hat{T}^{\mu\nu}(\tau,x)e^{-\beta(\hat{H}-\mu\hat{N})}\right]}{\mathcal{Z}}.\tag{1}
\end{equation}

where $\tau=it$ and $\mathcal{Z}=\operatorname{Tr}\left[e^{-\beta(\hat{H}-\mu\hat{N})}\right]$. Since $T^{\mu\nu}$ is originally derived by varying the classical action and is a function of $x$, $t$, this looks to me as if we started with the operator $\int_0^{T}dt\int{dx}^3\hat{T}^{\mu\nu}(t,x)$ defined on a region of Minkowski spacetime and Wick rotated it into Euclidean spacetime.

I would have guessed that the statistical average of the energy-momentum tensor would be given by

\begin{equation}
      \left<\hat{T}^{\mu\nu}(t,x)\right>=\frac{\operatorname{Tr}\left[\hat{T}^{\mu\nu}(t,x)e^{-\beta(\hat{H}-\mu\hat{N})}\right]}{\mathcal{Z}},\tag{2}
\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}
      \left<\int_0^Tdt\int{dx^3}\hat{T}^{\mu\nu}(t,x)\right>=\frac{\operatorname{Tr}\left[\int_0^Tdt\int{dx^3}\hat{T}^{\mu\nu}(t,x)e^{-\beta(\hat{H}-\mu\hat{N})}\right]}{\mathcal{Z}},\tag{3}
\end{equation}

if it was defined over a spacetime region. So my questions are:
(i) why use (1) instead of (2) or (3) to determine the statistical average of the energy-momentum tensor? (ii) If you want to find the thermal average of an operator $\hat{O}(t)$ that is originally dependent on $t$, is it important to first transform it via $t\to-i\tau$ and then take its statistical average $\left<\hat{O}(\tau)\right>$? (iii) Are we really looking for (3), but we just Wick rotate it to make the expression more mathematically well behaved?

Comment: (3) is the same as (1), no?

Comment: I don't think so. For instance, $\hat{T}^{\mu\nu}(t,x)$ in (3), typically has a term that looks like $\hat{\bar{\psi}}i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\hat{\psi}$, but in (1) it looks like $\hat{\bar{\psi}}(-\gamma^0\partial/\partial{\tau}+i\gamma^i\partial_i)\hat{\psi}$, which is at least syntactically different.